# Get the last N periods from a date column, regardless the period (year, month, day, hour, etc.)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have different tables with data. In some tables data is loaded quearterly, in others monthly/daily etc.

Every table has ReportedDate column. What I like to do is to be able to filter only the last N periods. If it is days for example, the last 3 days. The problem is I cannot use `GETDATE() - 3` for example, because the data is loaded for workdays and not holidays and weekends.

I have tried to use `ROW_NUMBER()` `PARTITION BY` ReportedDate but it works really slow.
I would appreciate suggestions.
A sample of a table:

```
+-----------+-----------------------------+
| Indicator |        ReportedDate         |
+-----------+-----------------------------+
|    0.2917 | 2020-08-12 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.261919 | 2020-08-13 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.259211 | 2020-08-14 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.201075 | 2020-08-17 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.250153 | 2020-08-18 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.333093 | 2020-08-19 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.976495 | 2020-08-20 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.759739 | 2020-08-21 00:00:00.0000000 |
|   1.17279 | 2020-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  0.285365 | 2020-08-25 00:00:00.0000000 |
+-----------+-----------------------------+

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Indicator, ReportedDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ReportedDate ORDER BY ReportedDate desc) as periods 
FROM indicatorTable) a
where periods <= 2
```

Another example - table with stock prices:

```
+--------+--------+-------------------------+
| Ticker | Price  |          Date           |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+
| AAPL   | 116.03 | 2020-11-25 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 115.17 | 2020-11-24 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 113.85 | 2020-11-23 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 117.34 | 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 118.64 | 2020-11-19 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 118.03 | 2020-11-18 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 119.39 | 2020-11-17 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   |  120.3 | 2020-11-16 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 119.26 | 2020-11-13 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 119.21 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    |  124.2 | 2020-11-25 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 124.42 | 2020-11-24 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 120.09 | 2020-11-23 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 116.94 | 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 117.18 | 2020-11-19 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 116.77 | 2020-11-18 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    |  117.7 | 2020-11-17 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 118.36 | 2020-11-16 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 116.85 | 2020-11-13 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    |  114.5 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 213.87 | 2020-11-25 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 213.86 | 2020-11-24 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 210.11 | 2020-11-23 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 210.39 | 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 212.42 | 2020-11-19 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 211.08 | 2020-11-18 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 214.46 | 2020-11-17 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 217.23 | 2020-11-16 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 216.51 | 2020-11-13 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 215.44 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+
```

What I want is to take the results for the last two periods, in this case:

```
+--------+--------+-------------------------+
| Ticker | Price  |          Date           |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+
| AAPL   | 116.03 | 2020-11-25 00:00:00.000 |
| AAPL   | 115.17 | 2020-11-24 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    |  124.2 | 2020-11-25 00:00:00.000 |
| IBM    | 124.42 | 2020-11-24 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 213.87 | 2020-11-25 00:00:00.000 |
| MSFT   | 213.86 | 2020-11-24 00:00:00.000 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and expected output. Also, include the set of tables to reproduce.

Comment: I shared the code. The tables are pretty much the same as the one I shared with more columns. But the other columns are not relevant. I just want to be able to get a number of periods back without the need to know which was the last date in any of the tables.

Comment: @Yana could you provide sample data and the desired result? It is still confusing what you need as result.

Comment: I added additional table where the idea is the same as with indicator table. I hope it explains better what I need as a result. The idea is not to hard code it. I want to be able to choose the last two days or the last two months/years/quarters etc. But not to write Date > 2020-11-23 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use dense_rank instead row_number

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Indicator, ReportedDate, dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY (select 1) ORDER BY ReportedDate desc) as periods 
FROM @t) a
where periods <= 2
```

Comment: In this case the rows from 24th and 25 of August cause it is a daily separation in this case.

Comment: But I have many indicators on the 25th for example and the row_number() takes each  2020-08-25 00:00:00.000 as a separate period. I don't understand why does this happen

Answer (score -1):

What if:

```
declare
    @t table (Indicator decimal(37,12), ReportedDate datetime)
insert into @t
select 0.2917 , cast('2020-08-12 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.261919 , cast('2020-08-13 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.259211 , cast('2020-08-14 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.201075 , cast('2020-08-17 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.250153 , cast('2020-08-18 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.333093 , cast('2020-08-19 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.976495 , cast('2020-08-20 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.759739 , cast('2020-08-21 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 1.17279 , cast('2020-08-24 00:00:00' as datetime)
union
select 0.285365, cast('2020-08-25 00:00:00' as datetime)


select top 3 * from @t
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: You should ignore the values in the Indicator column. I don't want to hard code anything. I want to be able to choose last N periods, regardless what these periods are.